# recreate \qed as \Box aligned under the current line

Tags: math-mode, positioning

I use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) on my Website which unfortunately doesn't support the use of `\qed` to create [QED symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#Electronic_forms).

So what I'm looking for is a way of recreate or rebuild the little square `\qed` usually offers.

I thought of aligning the `\Box` under the current line, but I don't know how..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to something you want to recreate? Or perhaps an image (even if you just post a link to the image; editors will embed the image in your post if needed). I am very unfamiliar with MathJax and therefore do not know much about answering this question; that is, whether this is website or (La)TeX-related.

Comment: Since it is on a web page, best way is to use the unicode character U+220E.

Comment: @Yannis: Good one! And its Unicode name is END OF PROOF even … I had no idea it existed. It looks like this: ∎

Answer (score 2):

Just to turn my comments into an answer to try and close the question. Since [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) is used on web pages the easiest way to add the QED sign is to use the unicode symbol for end of proof, which looks like this: ∎; The unicode character U+220E. Just type `&#x220E;` and if it need be enclose it within a span element.

Answer (score 2):

In a paragraph, append `<span style="float:right">∎</span>`. Creating a CSS class for it is even better.

In a display equation, hack it with `\tag*{∎}`.